# Program for General Form

Tags: conic-sections, calculator, programming

I am trying to find the general form of the conic sections, however, I am not able to create a program that runs it. I know the way you find it is by using B^2-4AC but I would like to write a program into my TI-84 that can tell what type of comic it is and put it into general form. Is there an app that already does this for a TI-84 or do I have to write a program (how do I write this specific program)?